# Perl - Webmin - "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl, strict, webmin, refs, virtualmin

I have a problem with module for Webmin, and I just want to resolve it with your help!

**This is error that I get when I try do add new VirtualHost to Nginx module:**

```
Error - Perl execution failed

Can't use string ("/home/www/website") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at virtualmin-nginx-lib.pl line 247.
```

I don't really know where is problem, because I'm not Perl programmer.

There is a file: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xJiUwNz4)

Comment: What does line 247 of virtualmin-nginx-lib.pl say? I'd say it involves something like `@{$mystring}`, where `$mystring` happens to be `/home/www/website`.

Comment: *“I don't really know where is problem, because I'm not Perl programmer.”* Then hire one to debug your script. While it is an entertaining challenge to debug something without running it, stackoverflow isn't the correct place to ask for this service.

Comment: it would be easier if you could include the line 247 and few lines before and after here.

Comment: I understand challenges to solve programming problem with a non-programmer, but not in an application like webmin what can cause some serious security holes. Really ask someone who knows what doing.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue:

http://www.virtualmin.com/node/23565

The solution seems to be adding the following line near the end of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, within the `http { ... }` block:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```